# как узнать изменилась ли веб страница?

Tags: php, javascript, html, веб-программирование, html5

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно узнать изменилась ли веб страница, не мониторя ее целый день? Например, проверяя контрольную сумму страницы или еще как-то. Идея такая - хочу сделать страницу с фреймом, в котором будет открываться нужная веб-страница и автоматом обновляться через каждые 30 секунд к примеру. Если что то изменилось, то пусть проиграет мелодию.

Comment: Что значит _не мониторя ее целый день_? Грубо говоря _обновляться через каждые 30 секунд_ и есть мониторинг...

Comment: @AGS17 чтобы звуковой сигнал давал понять, что страница изменилась, пока ты сидишь и смотришь стак оверфлоу на телефоне

Comment: имею ввиду не сидеть весь день перед монитором

Comment: Ну так просто делайте запрос на страницу и проверяйте `Content-Length`, к примеру. Если разный - гудите и обновляйте фрейм

Comment: @AGS17 а можно поподробнее как использовать ее?

Comment: Сделали `HTTP` запрос - сохранили `Content-Length`, через 30 сек сделали еще раз - проверили новый `Content-Length` с сохранненным старым (если разные - гудите и обновляетесь), и снова сделали через 30 сек и тд

Comment: @AGS17 `md5` - надежнее.

Comment: @E_p вот именно, неизвестно, что у него там обновляется. Курс валюты, например, в жестком формате 3 цифры после запятой. Length ничего не покажет.

Comment: @E_p А как сделать чтобы проверял не всю страницу, а `div class='row1'` например.

Comment: помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @JabbarGuliyev Ну очевидно, что надо парсить контент. Тут или regex, или какой html парсер. А хэш считать от полученного контента.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно что вы хотите и какие условия, но вам определённо нужна интеграция со сторонним сервисом которые будут увеомляться о изменении на вашей странице и, например, слать уведомление на почту.

Это если вы не собираетесь держать открытой страницу всё время. Иначе никак.